# "Permission denied" running executable built with `-c -o`

Tags: makefile

this may sound stupid. but I only have .c file(openfile.c) and it looks like this:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char* path = argv[1];
    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH;

    int fd = open(path, O_WRONLY | O_EXCL | O_CREAT, mode);
    if(fd == -1){
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and i want to write a Makefile for it.So it shouldnt be hard. The Makefile looks like this:

```
openfile: openfile.c 
    gcc -c -o openfile openfile.c
```

because i dont have/need a openfile.h so i just need one openfile.c. An d it compiles and when i run the ./openfile, bang, it says: bash: ./openfile: Permission denied

so wheres the problem? do i have to write a .h file?

Comment: Fun fact - you don't need a Makefile at all. `make openfile` will just work. Because of implicit rules.

Comment: Don't you need to add an argument to your ./openfile. It is trying to open arg[1]. This may be your error.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you don't need `-c`. When you pass `-c` to `gcc` it doesn't perform linking step, so you actually get o-file.

Comment: Why the permission error then? Is there another `openfile` there?

Comment: Permission error is because your file doesn't have execution flag. It doesn't need one since it is not a runnable binary.

Comment: It should be called `openfile.o` indeed.